# Retrofit2 won't return everything and suspends current threads

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm working around using Retrofit2 to access REST API.
This is codes I used for accessing to web server.

```
public class ServiceGenerator extends Application{

   private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://BaseURLOfAPI")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

   public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
    if (authToken != null) {
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Token " + authToken)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());


                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
    }

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass); 
   }
}

public interface UserInfoAPI{
  @GET("something/something2")
  Call<UserInfo> getUserInfo();
}

// Inside of onCreate in an Activity
UserInfoApi api = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserInfoApi.class,somethingToken);
Call<UserInfo> call = api.getUserInfo(); // <- stack here
```

My android application hung up by calling api.getUserInfo. By inspecting this method deeply,`Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations()` in `retrofit2.ServiceMethod.createResponseConverter` is the cause.

I wonder this method makes something eternal loop since the method not throws any exceptions. And logcat outputs `Suspending all threads took : ??? ms` a lot.

Is there any suggestion to find this reason?

Comment: What is your service generator class

Comment: Oh, that is my wrong. I edited my program.

Comment: That's weird, you should set a converter factory of some sort.

Comment: What did you mean "converter factory" ?

Comment: Where is your `builder` declaration ?

Comment: @LimeStreem : @EpicPandaForce want to say you need to add converter factory in your `builder` instance. ex:`private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(your_base_url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());`

Comment: Oh my wrong, but it is same as @pRaNaY. I edited my code in my question.